# Id instead of String when displaying foreign key field in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return the name of the `pricing` field but all I get is its foreign key id instead. What am I doing wrong here? I looked at some similiar issues on here but I didn't find anything that resembled my situation.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "assignedteams",
            "agent",
            "facility",
            "organisor",
            "avatar",
        )


class UserSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = (
            "user",
            "pricing",
            "status",
        )


class UserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):

    profile = UserProfileSerializer(source="userprofile")
    subscription = UserSubscriptionSerializer(source="usersubscription")

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserDetailsSerializer.Meta.fields + ('profile', 'subscription',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        userprofile_serializer = self.fields['profile']
        userprofile_instance = instance.userprofile
        userprofile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile', {})
    
        usersubscription_serializer = self.fields['subscription']
        usersubscription_instance = instance.usersubscription
        usersubscription_data = validated_data.pop('usersubscription', {})

        # update the userprofile fields
        userprofile_serializer.update(userprofile_instance, userprofile_data)
        usersubscription_serializer.update(usersubscription_instance, usersubscription_data)

        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

Comment: can you share your UserSubscriptionSerializer code ?

Comment: can you share the models here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily add a new field representation or override the pricing field when want to represent data
so in your serializer add the following code

```
class UserSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = (
            "user",
            "pricing",
            "status",
        )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['pricing_name'] = instance.pricing.name # or replace the name with your pricing name field
        return data
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options to solve this problem.

**option1:**
If you want to return only the name of your pricing model you can use SlugRelatedField to do it.

Example:

```
class UserSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pricing = serializers.SlugRelatedField('name', readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = (
            "user",
            "pricing",
            "status",
        )
```

**Option2:**
If you want to return the Pricing object you can create a new ModelSerializer for your Pricing model and use it.

Example:

```
class PricingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pricing
        fields = ["id","name"]

class UserSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pricing = PricingSerializer(readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = (
            "user",
            "pricing",
            "status",
        )
```

There are some other options that can you use but you must explain more about your problem can I will help you with.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying `pricing` returned FK id, so i assume `pricing` column inside `Subscription model` is a FK to another model, let's assume it `Pricing` model.

You can create a serializer for `Pricing` and use it on `UserSubscriptionSerializer`,
like the way you created `UserProfileSerializer` and `UserSubscriptionSerializer` for `UserSerializer`

But, using directly a nested serializer will give you problem while doing write operation since as far i can understand you are accepting `pricing` as FK value when `creating or updating`

To solve this issue you can do some **if/else** on `get_fields()` method

```
class UserSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = (
            "user",
            "pricing",
            "status",
        )

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        # make sure request is passed through context
        if self.context['request'] and self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            fields['pricing']=PricingSerializer()
        return fields
```

Now coming back to the question, since you only need the `pricing` `name` which i assume name is a column on `Pricing model`
simply rewrite the previous code as

```
def get_fields(self):
    fields = super().get_fields()
    # make sure request is passed through context
    if self.context['request'] and self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
        fields['pricing'] = serializers.CharField(source='pricing.name', read_only=True)
    return fields
```

P.S: I haven't tested this code on my computer